# Consuming SOAP service with RestTemplate (POST) throwing 405 Method Not allowed

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate

I am trying to consume a soap service from Spring RestTemplate in Java. I have added some headers and request parameters and dispatched it into the PostForEntity Method but its throwing **405 Method not allowed**.

I know the reason that the server is taking this call as GET however, it can only be post. 
I have tried to change my headers and altered my request but nothing achieved. Can anybody suggest what is wrong with my approach / code?

```
        String host = "172.18.101.2";
        String port = "80";

        System.out.println("Using proxy: " + host + ":" + port);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port);

        SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("SOAPAction", "http://ApiConnectFTwsdlDefinition/FundsTransfer");
        headers.add("X-IBM-Client-Id", "0146b9a4-7e99-4c83-8e9e-6049cfec55da");
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer AAIkMDE0NmI5YTQtN2U5OS00YzgzLThlOWUtNjA0OWNmZWM1NWRhV8EJd7oTPaijRicPTNxSH_h21meA_4h3Ty_QDOoXXRPC2f_MLk0BLBx4Q0DWZMHTfwTwur3BaiiF7y9uFcCkkj8fuTGK_yujrtuRY-4AZMK8hRPSppw3HhKYR84R9c9Wy9j6czOKqUklfLO6Zgb19A");

        MultivaluedMap body = new MultivaluedHashMap();     

        JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject();           

        requestObj.put("SystemName", "CDC");
        requestObj.put("RequestID", "222");
        requestObj.put("TenantID", "abc11323===+");
        requestObj.put("CreditAccount", "0010000108290010");
        requestObj.put("DebitAmount", "100");
        requestObj.put("MappingID", "Remarks");
        requestObj.put("Narration", "remarks");

        body.add("data", requestObj.toString());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://221.120.211.69:443/abl-api/uat/ApiConnectFTwsdlDefinitionHttpService?wsdl", requestObj.toString(), String.class);

        System.out.println("Status Code >>> " + response.getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `RestTemplate` for consuming SOAP Services, Use spring [web services client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html)

Comment: I have also used HTTPURLConnection and Jersey. But still same response. can you suggest any change in the existing code?

Comment: Few problems I can see in your code are - First, you are setting content type as xml and posting json, i am not sure how it is handled in other end, Second, you are not adding headers to the request, it is simply declared and never used, even the `MultivaluedMap` body. In both the cases it should throw 415 instead of 405. I have tried RestTemplate to hit public SOAP api's considering the above two things I have mentioned, it just works fine.

Comment: I have sent the request header in the postforentity method (2nd parameter). The json object is the request header.

Comment: At least in the code which you have posted, I can see the 2nd parameter is the json object itself, and json object has no headers, it has data,  and the headers are in `HttpHeaders` which is never used. If you need to post data along with headers your second parameter should be HttpEntity which you can create like this - `HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestObj.toString(), headers);`